# SPARQL: How to get the largest value when a subject has multiple objects

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am trying to write a SPARQL query that would compare multiple values of a subject and would return the largest one:

For example, I have the following triple:

```
<http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> a skos:Concept ;
geo:asWKT "+016.084444",
    "+016.084499 " ;
skos:prefLabel "Glogau" .
```

I need my query to first check the `geo:asWKT` values:

if `"+016.084444" - "+016.084499 " < 0.01` (the absolut value),

then if valid choose the larger one (i.e. `"+016.084499"`). There might be cases that there is only one `asWKT` value.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if ">0.01"? What if there are three values?

Comment: I didn"t fully understand the question, but largest value sounds like `group by` = `max`. Regarding the second part, `BIND` in combination with `IF` might work here.

Comment: The sample data you provided is not a triple.  It is 4 triples, which I show here as such. `{ <http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> a skos:Concept . <http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> geo:asWKT "+016.084444" .
<http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> geo:asWKT "+016.084499 " .
<http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> skos:prefLabel "Glogau" . }`

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for the tips. But my problem is that I don't know how to separate the two object values. So here is want to compare `"+016.084444"`  and `"+016.084499 "` which are both assigned to `geo:asWKT`.

To use IF statement I need to first have them as Value1 and Value2.

Comment: @TallTed You are right we have more than 1 triple here. But I thought
`<http://data.judaicalink.org/data/Glogau> geo:asWKT "+016.084444",
    "+016.084499 " ;` is considered as one triple, but when you put it separately as you did seems easier to deal with.

Comment: Each set of Subject, Predicate, and Object comprises one triple. The comma and semicolon punctuation are shorthand, so you can blend multiple triples into a single line of Turtle, and avoid repeating the Predicate and Subject, respectively -- but such lines of Turtle are like this compound sentence; i.e., they're made of multiple statements (i.e., multiple triples).

Comment: We don't know enough about your data and your goals to provide simple advice.